# Getting "oModel.read is not a function" error

Tags: odata, sapui5, odata-v4

While performing Read operation on `V4 ODatamodel` I'm getting an error saying

> oModel.read is not a function

**Code**

[image: Model declaration]

**Error**

[image: Error screenshot]

Please let me know how to correct if I did something wrong.

Comment: The read method does not exist on OData V4, only OData V2:
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel/methods/read

Comment: I see,then how we would perform the read operation on V4 ?

Comment: Usually through data binding in the view, if you bind lets say your /Products to a table, the bind itself will trigger a request to your OData service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is expected.

> read method does not exist in oData Model V4.

See below:
[read is not a function in V4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xefD.png)

However, you can do the same thing with oData V2(recommended approach for working with oData as V4 has still some features missing)

[Restrictions with oData V4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6QAI.png)

[oData V2 vs oData V4](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_uiaddon20/2.05/en-US/ab/d4d7c7548d4c29ab8364d3904a6d74/frameset.htm)

Nevertheless, if you need to bind the response items later with a table, you can 
do it as:

```js
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataModel({
    groupId: "$auto",
    serviceUrl: "url",
    synchronizationMode: "None",
    operationMode: "Server"
  }),
  oSettings = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
    bOnlyLarge: false,
    bFilterGermany: false
  });
var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table({
  columns: [{
    label: "ProductName",
    template: new sap.m.Text({
      text: "{Country}"
    }),
    sortProperty: "ProductName"
  }]
});
oTable.setModel(oModel);

oTable.bindRows({
  path: "/Products"
});
```

Comment: Thankq for the wonderful explanation..:) I would really appreciate if you could make me understand the difference between V2 OData model and OData model as well.!

Comment: I have added one link in the above answer for the differences. Are you looking for something specifically?

Comment: Yes, in terms of CRUD operations

Answer (score 0):

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataModel({
    /* send requests directly. Use $auto for batch request wich will be send automatically on before rendering */
  groupId : "$direct",
    /* I'll just quote the API documentary:
  Controls synchronization between different bindings which refer to the same data for the case data changes in one binding.
  Must be set to 'None' which means bindings are not synchronized at all; all other values are not supported and lead to an error.
  */
  synchronizationMode : "None",
  /*
  Root URL of the service to request data from.
  */
    serviceUrl : "http://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService/",
  /*
  optional. Group ID that is used for update requests. If no update group ID is specified, mParameters.groupId is used.:
  updateGroupId : "$direct"
  */
  });
```